# How to avoid axes labels overlapping matplotlib python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

How do I avoid these axes labels/titles from overlapping? It's pretty annoying. I've tried tight_layout and constrainedlayout=True but neither works!

[image]

Comment: please paste the code here

Comment: Increase `figsize`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I've tried but the font will enlarge accordingly. I'm trying to fix fontsize and see if it gets better. But any other comments are appreciated.

Comment: Put carriage returns in your labels “\n”.  You don’t have enough room for such long labels.